# Linked Structures

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm currently studying about Linked Structures in Java. I am working with a class to make Nodes. Specifically a method which will concatenate two nodes and return a third which represents this union. Node1 ={1,2,3}; Node2 = {4,5,6} concat(Node1, Node2) = {1,2,3,4,5,6})
The code is bellow. As part of the exercise the three Nodes should be independent of each other. My solution was copying the Nodes with a copy() method. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this. 
Thank you.

```
public class Node {

int data;
Node next;

Node(int data){
    this.data = data;
}

Node concat(Node list1, Node list2) {
    // The copy method basically creates a copy of the given Node.
    Node an = copy(list1); Node b = copy(list2);
    Node a = an;
    while(a != null) {
        if(a.next == null) {break;}
        a = a.next;
    }
    a.next = b;
    return an;
}

 Node copy(Node p) {
     Node nan = new Node(p.data);
     Node n = nan;
     p = p.next;


     while(p != null) {
         n.next = new Node(p.data);
         n = n.next;
         p = p.next;
     }
     return nan;
     }
     }
```

Comment: Define "optimal". I suggest you try asking on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Comment: thanks! Didn't know there was a Code Review. Though, rather than the question of optimal or not, I was curious to know if there was a better way to make the third node independently without having to copy the other two nodes.

Comment: The problem being that "better" is *opinion*. At least optimal could be "time" or "space".

Comment: All I want to know is if copying the Node is a necessity to keep the Nodes independent of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the nodes in all the chains to be independent, you have to copy them.

Anyway, here's a slightly simplified version of your code:

```
Node concat(Node list1, Node list2) {
    Node clone = copy(list1);
    Node iter = clone;
    while (iter.next != null) {
        iter = iter.next;
    }
    iter.next = copy(list2);
    return clone;
}

Node copy(Node other) {
    Node clone = new Node(other.data);
    Node iter = clone;
    while (other.next != null) {
        other = other.next;
        iter.next = new Node(other.data);
        iter = iter.next;
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: thanks man, I forgot to add the .next at the condition of the loops!